# Lua Function declaration

Tags: lua

I am confused as to how function is declared in lua.  What i want to know is the order the function definition is in the file. In my example, sample 1 works where as sample 2 wouldn't compile.

Sample 1

```
--This works, sample 1
function finddir(lpath)
local localfs =  require "luci.fs"

if localfs.isdirectory(lpath) then
  print "we have directory"
  else
    print "Directory not found"
    end
end

**local ltest = finddir("/proc/net/")**
-- END --
```

Sample 2

```
--This Sample fails to compile, Sample 2
**local ltest = finddir("/proc/net/")**

function finddir(lpath)
local localfs =  require "luci.fs"

if localfs.isdirectory(lpath) then
  print "we have directory"
  else
    print "Directory not found"
    end
end
-- END --
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions in Lua are first-class values.

In the first example, the function is defined, in another word, the variable `finddir` has a value of type `function`. So you can call it.

In the second example, the function has not been defined when you call it, in another word, the varialbe `finddir` has a value `nil`, thus you can't call it.

It's not that different with other types, e.g:

```
n = 42
local a = n + 3  --fine
```

vs

```
local a = n + 3  --error, n is nil
n = 42
```